# PM2 setup on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, pm2

I have a question about pm2 running on the remote server.
So I have created the Twilio call using node js to send the SMS to the user when the button is clicked.
I have created the smsMessage.js containing the `app.post` and connected to port 3000 using the localhost.

Then from there, I have called the `smsMessage` using the ajax call. Up to this point, everything works but when I tried uploading to the remote server, it will return saying that

> "POST http://localhost:3000/smsMessage net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

On the remote server, I have installed the pm2 globally and run by typing

```
pm2 start ./smsMessage.js
```

The connection status seems to be good because it says online. I really don't know where I can approach this problem. Is there something missing before I upload it to the remote server?

Comment: From where do you send the request? From the server itself? Using NodeJS?

Comment: I have a page called Basic.email.Form which contains the ajax call using "url: "http://localhost:3000/smsMessage" and that will work when user click on the button. Yes, using node js.

Comment: Are you opening that page on your own computer, in your browser? (i.e. not on the server). If so, it's normal that `localhost` doesn't work, because it's the address of your machine, not the server's. You need to replace `localhost` with the IP or domain of your server. And you might need to configure nginx or Apache on the server to accept connections on port 3000

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The sms sends on my own computer setup. Let say if my ip or 45.45.45.45:8000 and make my node js to run on 45.45.45.45:3000. Will that work? Im new to node js so forgive me if I am asking common sense question.

Comment: It's kind of unclear to me how everything is setup. You have a local server on your computer which exposes a webpage on `http://localhost:8000`? And from this page, you want to send an Ajax request to your remote server, which exposes your smsMessage app on `http://45.45.45.45:3000`? If so, your Ajax request should be sent to `http://45.45.45.45:3000`. But since the host of your page and the remote server are different, you need to make sure CORS is enabled in smsMessage.js, and that your remote server lets requests go through port 3000

Comment: For the test, I am running on ISS and created the port 8000 to run it on the localhost. From there I created node js that runs on port 3000 so that i can make a ajax call to send the sms from twilio. This project was done by someone else and given to me so its so hard for me to know what he did in the backend. I tried looking his code but so hard to understand and keep in track of the code. But thank you for your help and time.